# Email questionnaire with checkboxes/radio buttons?

Tags: forms, email, checkbox, radio-button, html-email

I know I could simply make a html form on a website and email a link to it, or send the html as an email which posts to the website and try to deal with the errors/warnings for different peoples mail clients.

But, due to a specific request from a client, I am wondering if there is a way I could send an email, a questionnaire, with the same checkbox elements which then user receiving the questionnaire simply checks and sends back as a reply to the sender?

Comment: The day after marking the correct answer for this I got a form via email :) Seems like https://mysurveylab.com/ provides forms via email, see the screenshot here https://i.gyazo.com/0d0cf5a542687eaa7d29bd5fa8f8b981.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very well supported across email clients, and will even throw some scary looking error messages to your recipients. You will be much better served linking to a landing page.

More info: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my question, I already know this. I was looking for more of a static alternative where the actual form would be sent back as a static message with the checkboxes filled in. Instead of using a form with a post request.

Comment: Going to mark this as the correct answer since it brings up the issues with including forms directly in emails. Please do consider the answer by @John below which brings up parameters in links. This would be a great option if you are sending an email asking customers to respond on a 1-10 scale. Clicking a number could have a different response such as "Thanks for the 10! Can you tell us why you liked the experience?" or "We are sorry you are not happy with your order, we always try to improve what we do so could you leave some feedback below?"

Answer (score 1):

Email only supports html and css. I think Google has something like that, but it is not widely supported.

Generally, neither html of css can submit a form or (if the form even displays) acknowledge which form fields are populated/checked. Pretty much all you have is hyperlinks.

Passing parameters in your hyperlink would allow you to pre populate a form, but that is about as tricky as you can get.

Something like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/register?name=joe&email=joe@email.com">Register Now</a>
```

You could then use PHP for example to populate the landing page form with the values. I know it doesn't help much for a questionnaire, but that's all we have to work with in email.